# MySQL on LAN not working when IPTables are enabled

Tags: php, mysql, apache, iptables, centos6.5

I have two Centos VM. The IP Address on VM_1 is *10.99.0.10* and VM_2 is *10.99.0.12*. Apache and PHP are in VM_1 and MySQL is in VM_2. Both are having IPTables  rules. VM_2 is working fine with rules. Now I am Testing from VM_1.

First, I disabled VM_1 IPTables  and connect to VM_2 MySQL (connected successfully).

```
[root@foster ~]# service IPTables  stop
IPTables : Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
[root@foster ~]# mysql -h 10.99.0.12 -u root -p
Enter password:

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 16
Server version: 5.6.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Next, I enabled VM_1 IPTables  and connect to VM_2 MySQL (It never respond in hours and hours also).

```
[root@foster ~]# service IPTables  start
IPTables : Applying firewall rules:                         [  OK  ]
[root@foster ~]# mysql -h 10.99.0.12 -u root -p
Enter password:
```

What is wrong with my IPTables rules? My rules are in [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/yVRA1dGD).

Comment: [Your question is better suited here](http://serverfault.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the method you enable `MySQL` traffic:

```
# Allow MySQL private Networking
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 10.99.0.12 --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

These rules have two issues:

1. They allow outgoing `MySQL` traffic from `VM_1` only if the connection was first initiated from `VM_2` (`10.99.0.12`).
2. They specify the port `3306` as the client's (`VM_1`) port rather than as the server's (`VM_2`) port.

A more suitable rule set would be as follows:

```
# Allow MySQL private Networking
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 3306 -m state --state NEW, ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -p tcp -s 10.99.0.12 --sport 3306 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Awesome! I just replaced with your rule set and it works. Just curious "is this rule set safe/secure?". Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think so, though I'm no expert. As a rule of thumb, it's better to allow new traffic to be initiated at the local machine than elsewhere. Also, it's always wise to restrict the allowed IP address range. For example, I would add the destination IP to the first rule. Same goes for the server - if you can restrict the incoming requests to a set of known IP addresses, do so. For more information, just google and learn. [This wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/simple_stateful_firewall) can be a good starting point.

Comment: You can also change the default ports, though they can still be detected through tools like `nmap`.